# Sort files with Batch from one to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I have the following structure:

- SourceFolder

  - Folder 1

    - File1.pdf
    - File2.pdf
  - Folder 2

    - File3.pdf
    - File4.pdf
- DestinationFolder

  - Folder1
  - Folder2

How can a Batch-file loop through the SourceFolder and copy every file in the correct subfolder in the DestinationFolder? I'm not very familiar with Batch-files, so it would be great if you could support me. :-)

Thank you!

Comment: Please copy and paste the code you are trying to make work into the question. See the help information on how SO works. https://stackoverflow.com/help SO is not a free code writing service. Help us help you.

Comment: `xcopy /s`? (see `xcopy /?`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exactly recreate the subfolders and fils in the destination folder that are under the source folder you can just use Robocopy:

This will only list the files and folders to be copied:

```
Robocopy "C:\Source\Folder" "C:\Destination\Folder" * /MT:64 /S /E /L
```

This will copy them using the backup method and only retry a locked file twice:

```
Robocopy "C:\Source\Folder" "C:\Destination\Folder" * /MT:64 /S /E /B /R:2 /W:2
```